# Angularjs: How make a directive active only one templates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using a directive to register keyboard input to allow for keyboard shortcuts (hotkeys) in one of the views. This works great, but when moving to another view (another template) the directive is still active and the hotkeys work there too. How can I limit the hotkey functionality to only the view where the  tag is used. Needless to say: I am a newbie at this, so please be patient :-)

My app.js:

```
app.directive('shortcut', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        link:    function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs){
            jQuery(document).on('keypress', function(e){
              scope.$apply(scope.keyPressed(e));
           });
        }
     };
});
```

In the top portion of index.html:

```
     <ul class="nav nav-pills" data-ng-controller="NavbarController">
                <li data-ng-class="{'active':getClass('/customers')}"><a href="#/customers">Customers/a></li>
                <li data-ng-class="{'active':getClass('/orders')}"><a href="#/orders">Orders</a></li>
     </ul>
```

In the template orders.html:

```
<shortcut></shortcut>
```

In the controller used by the template there is a function that takes action depending on which key is pressed:

```
$scope.keyPressed = function(e, scope) {
    //.
    //.
    //.
    switch(e.which) {
     //Key h is pushed
     case 104:
     case 72:
         $scope.openDialog("h"); 
         break;
    //Key i is pushed
     case 105:
     case 73:
         $scope.openDialog("i"); 
         break;
        //key t is pushed
     case 116:
     case 84:
         $scope.openDialog("t"); 
         break;
            //Enter is pushed
     case 13:
         $scope.insertOrder();
         break;
     default:
         console.log("Another key");
     }
}
```

The thing I try to do is, within the direcive, detect which view is active and only act on the correct view, but I do not know if this i possible or advisable. What is the correct or preferred way to deal with this?

Comment: So orders.html is only rendered when your shortcut-view is active, but when you switch to main-view(and the template + shortcut directive) is gone, the shortcuts still work? Maybe you need to unregister the event listener when the scope is destroyed? A plunker with the general structure would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unbind the event listener once the scope of the element (on which the directive is applied) is destroyed.
So, you can do something like:

```
var keypressHandler = function(e){
    scope.$apply(scope.keyPressed(e));
});

jQuery(document).on('keypress', keypressHandler);
iElement.on('$destroy', function() {
    jQuery(document).off('keypress', keypressHandler);
});
```

You can read about $destroy [HERE](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope).